# Angular version 5, Bootstrap

Tags: css, angular5, ng-bootstrap

How can i edit the original bootstrap angular date picker style sheet according to my desire
here is the link
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#basic
 i need to edit the color of this date picker in my file.

Comment: have you tried creating your own ID for it and changing the ID color to see if that would change the date picker color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using **angular cli**, There is a global **style.css/style.scss**  in the root folder(**src**). Here you can add your custom styles for datepicker inspecting the element to find the classes to override the styles.

**Add this to style.css/scss file**

```
.ngb-dp-day .btn-light {
    background: green !important;
}

.ngb-dp-day .bg-primary {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply F12 (Inspect element) and see they styles:
[image]

**Add to your css:(use `!important` to prevent ovvride)**

```
ngb-datepicker{
background-color: red!important; 
}
```

[image]

**See result:**
[image]

Comment: tell me for more help